# R - insert all column types at once in a function

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

If I wanted to attribute the type `character` to all my columns at once, using any function, as for example `spark_read_csv` from `sparklyr`, I would do something like

```
flights <- spark_read_csv(sc, "flights_spark", 
                          path =  "/path/flights.csv", 
                          memory = TRUE, 
                          columns = list(
                            Year = "character",
                            Month = "character",
                            DayofMonth = "character",
                            DayOfWeek = "character",
                            DepTime = "character",
                            CRSDepTime = "character",
                            ArrTime = "character",
                            CRSArrTime = "character",
                            UniqueCarrier = "character",
                            FlightNum = "character",
                            TailNum = "character",
                            ActualElapsedTime = "character",
                            CRSElapsedTime = "character",
                            AirTime = "character",
                            ArrDelay = "character",
                            DepDelay = "character",
                            Origin = "character",
                            Dest = "character",
                            Distance = "character",
                            TaxiIn = "character",
                            TaxiOut = "character",
                            Cancelled = "character",
                            CancellationCode = "character",
                            Diverted = "character",
                            CarrierDelay = "character",
                            WeatherDelay = "character",
                            NASDelay = "character",
                            SecurityDelay = "character",
                            LateAircraftDelay = "character"), 
                          infer_schema = FALSE)
```

Is there a way to make it less painful?

An example using `fread` from `data.table`:

```
iris <- data.table::fread("path/iris", colClasses = c(`Sepal.Length` = "character",
                                          `Sepal.Width` = "character",
                                          `Petal.Length` = "character",
                                          `Petal.Width` = "character",
                                          `Species` = "character",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all fields are `character` and you disabled schema inference a plain list of names would be sufficient:

```
spark_read_csv(sc,
  "flights_spark", 
  path =  "/path/flights.csv", 
  columns = list("Year", "Month", ..., "LateAircraftDelay")
  infer_schema = FALSE)
```

although without schema inference you should be able to skip it completely, without significant performance penalty.

```
spark_read_csv(sc,
  "flights_spark", 
  path =  "/path/flights.csv", 
  infer_schema = FALSE)
```

In general case (different types) a named list would to the trick:

```
names_ <- c("Year", "Month", ..., "LateAircraftDelay")
dtypes <- list("integer", "integer", ..., "string")

spark_read_csv(sc,
  "flights_spark", 
  path =  "/path/flights.csv", 
  columns = setNames(dtypes, names_),
  infer_schema = FALSE)
```